# С какой версией Python использовать Django?

Tags: python, django

Вопрос о  Django, Для какой версии питона его ставить  2.7 или 3.4?

Или ему без разницы?

Хотелось бы для 3.4

Но книжку купил (немного старая) там рекомендуют 2.Х

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я в пяти проектах использую 2.7, в новых двух решили использовать 3.4, проблемы с библиотеками есть, но максимум в 20% случаев, да и то они быстро решаются при помощи 2to3 и доработки напильником. Единственное на что я потратил не мало времени это https://github.com/adw0rd/lettuce-py3 и https://github.com/adw0rd/salad-py3

А вот год-два назад приходилось 80% фиксить библиотек, так что прогресс есть. В новый проект я без сомнения возьму py3.4

Answer (score 6):

Разработчики Django рекомендует использовать Python 3, так как он чаще быстрее и имеет лучшую поддержку. Все популярные библиотеки в конечном счете перейдут на третью версию. Но выбрав Python 3, Вы лишаетесь возможности напрямую использовать библиотеки написанные на Python 2. Это особенно важно, если планируется использовать старую библиотеку не имеющую порта на Python 3.

Следуют предварительно узнать какие зависимости будут у проекта, и исходить из этого.

Comment: Плюс за ответ. Только стратегия при отсутствии поддержки версии 3 в нужном пакете должна быть следующая: _добавить поддержку своими силами, предложить изменение автору_. Этим вы принесёте больше пользы сообществу и приблизите переход на 3.

Answer (score 0):

Сейчас без разницы какую версию питона использовать 2.7 или 3тью ветку, используй ту которая нравится, но помни в 3 питоне кодировка по умолчанию UTF-8

Answer (score 0):

Около полу года назад начал использовать py3. Есть проблемы с некоторыми библиотеками, но в большинстве случае есть более прогрессивная альтернатива. А если нет, то это отличная возможность сделать свой вклад :)